# NSArrayController subclass setFetchLimit in fetchWithRequest

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsarraycontroller, nspopupbutton

I have a NSPopupButton that is bound to a CoreData backed NSArrayController.

I subclassed the NSArrayController to set a fetchLimit and SortDescriptor.

The problem is the following:

The FetchLimit only applies on the initial load. When entries are added to the CoreData Store programatically, the NSPopupButton reflects and shows the new entries, but does not apply the fetch limit. I also tried to set the merge: parameter to NO, but this doesn't seem to affect the updates/refetches.

```
- (BOOL) fetchWithRequest:(NSFetchRequest *)fetchRequest 
                    merge:(BOOL)merge 
                    error:(NSError **)error
{

    if(fetchRequest)
        [fetchRequest setFetchLimit:10];

    NSLog(@"fetchWithRequest: %@", fetchRequest);
    return [super fetchWithRequest:fetchRequest merge:NO error:error];
}
```

am i missing something?

Comment: Your not trying to modify a fetch that was previously executed are you?

Comment: The above code is the overwritten fetchWithRequest method in the NSArrayController subclass and i just set the fetchLimit of the request and pass it through.

Comment: Did you have any success?